# How do I run a chi-square goodness-of-fit test in tbl_summary() R

Tags: r, chi-squared

I have a one-dimensional matrix and I want to run a goodness of fit test. (See sample data bellow)

I have tried to run this test using chisq.test() in the tbl_summary() but it always gives me a different answer than when I create my own matrix or do the calculation by hand.

The tbl_summary code I use is:

```
tbl4 <- DentalHealth %>% select(Race, PG_Level)
tbl4 %>%
  tbl_summary(by = Race,
                  value = list(PG_Level ~ "PG>10000"),
    label = list(PG_Level ~ "PG>10000"),
    statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ c("{n}")),
    missing = "no") %>%
  add_p(everything() ~ "chisq.test", pvalue_fun = function(x) style_number(x, digits = 3)) %>%
  modify_header(label ~ "**Race groups**") %>%
  modify_caption("**Table 3.b Detection rates of PG greater than >10,000 cells in different races**") %>%
  bold_labels()
```

This table summary returns a p-value of 0.114. This is incorrect by my own manual calculations.

The table looks something like this:

| AA | CA | HA | p-value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 7 | 18 | .0114 |

When I run the test as below, I get the correct output:

```
observed <- c(15, 7, 18) 
expected <- c(1/3, 1/3, 1/3)
chisq.test(x=observed, p=expected)
```

output is correct:

```
> Chi-squared test for given probabilities
> 
> data:  observed
> X-squared = 4.85, df = 2, p-value = 0.08848
```

How can I get the correct p-value of 0.08848 to show up in my table?

---

Data:

```
structure(list(Race = c("HA", "CA", "HA", "CA", "HA", "HA", "HA", 
"HA", "AA", "CA", "AA", "CA", "CA", "HA", "AA", "AA", "CA", "HA", 
"HA", "HA", "HA", "AA", "CA", "AA", "CA", "HA", "HA", "AA", "HA", 
"AA", "HA", "HA", "HA", "AA", "HA", "CA", "AA", "HA", "CA", "CA", 
"AA", "HA", "HA", "AA", "HA", "CA", "AA", "AA", "CA", "CA", "HA", 
"CA", "CA", "HA", "HA", "CA", "HA", "AA", "HA", "AA", "AA", "CA", 
"AA", "CA", "AA", "CA", "CA", "HA", "AA", "AA", "CA", "CA", "CA", 
"CA", "AA", "HA", "AA", "HA", "HA", "CA", "AA", "HA", "HA", "AA", 
"CA", "CA", "HA", "CA", "CA", "HA", "AA", "CA", "CA", "HA", "HA", 
"CA", "CA", "CA", "HA", "AA", "CA", "AA", "HA", "HA", "AA", "HA", 
"AA", "HA", "AA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "HA", "HA", 
"HA", "AA", "HA", "HA", "AA", "CA", "AA", "HA", "CA", "HA", "CA", 
"HA", "CA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "HA", "HA", "AA", "CA", "CA", "HA", 
"HA", "HA", "CA", "HA", "AA", "CA", "HA", "CA", "HA", "AA", "CA", 
"AA", "AA", "CA", "HA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "HA", "CA", "CA", 
"CA", "AA", "CA", "CA", "HA", "CA", "CA", "HA", "CA", "CA", "AA", 
"CA", "AA", "CA", "HA", "HA", "CA", "HA", "CA", "HA", "AA", "CA", 
"CA", "HA", "AA", "CA", "HA", "CA", "CA", "AA", "HA", "HA", "HA", 
"HA", "HA", "HA", "AA", "HA", "CA", "HA", "HA", "CA", "HA", "CA", 
"CA", "HA", "AA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "HA", "HA", "AA", "HA", 
"HA", "AA", "HA", "HA", "AA", "HA", "AA", "HA", "HA", "CA", "CA", 
"CA", "HA", "AA", "HA", "CA", "AA", "AA", "HA", "CA", "HA", "AA", 
"HA", "CA", "HA", "HA", "AA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "HA", "HA", 
"CA", "HA", "CA", "CA", "AA", "HA", "HA", "HA", "HA", "HA", "HA", 
"CA", "HA", "HA", "CA", "CA", "AA", "CA", "HA", "CA", "CA", "HA", 
"HA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "HA", "CA", "CA", "CA", "HA", 
"HA", "HA", "HA", "HA", "CA", "CA", "HA", "CA", "AA", "HA", "AA", 
"AA", "HA", "HA", "AA", "HA", "CA", "CA", "HA", "AA", "AA", "AA", 
"AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", 
"AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", 
"AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", "AA", 
"AA", "AA", "AA"), PG_Level = c("PG>10000", "0", "0", "0", "PG>10000", 
"PG>10000", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "PG1~1000", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "PG1001~10000", "PG>10000", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "PG>10000", "PG1~1000", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"PG1001~10000", "0", "0", "PG1001~10000", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "PG>10000", "PG>10000", "PG>10000", "0", "0", "PG>10000", 
"0", "PG>10000", "PG>10000", "0", "PG1~1000", "0", "0", "PG>10000", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "PG1~1000", "PG>10000", "0", "0", "0", 
"PG1~1000", "PG1~1000", "0", "PG1~1000", "PG1~1000", "PG1~1000", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "PG1~1000", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "PG1001~10000", "0", "PG1001~10000", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"PG1001~10000", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "PG>10000", 
"0", "PG>10000", "0", "0", "0", "PG1~1000", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"PG1001~10000", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "PG>10000", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "PG>10000", "0", "0", "PG1001~10000", "PG>10000", 
"0", "0", "0", "PG>10000", "0", "PG1~1000", "0", "PG1~1000", 
"0", "PG>10000", "PG1~1000", "0", "PG>10000", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "PG1001~10000", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "PG>10000", "0", "PG1001~10000", 
"0", "0", "PG1~1000", "0", "0", "0", "0", "PG1~1000", "0", "0", 
"PG>10000", "PG1~1000", "0", "0", "0", "PG1~1000", "0", "PG>10000", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "PG>10000", "0", "0", "0", 
"PG>10000", "PG>10000", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "PG1~1000", "PG>10000", "0", "0", "0", "PG>10000", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "PG>10000", "0", "0", "PG1001~10000", 
"PG>10000", "0", "0", "PG>10000", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "PG>10000", "PG>10000", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"PG>10000", "0", "0", "0", "0", "PG1001~10000", "0", "0", "0", 
"PG1001~10000", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "PG1001~10000", 
"PG1001~10000", "PG1~1000", "0", "0", "PG1001~10000", "0", "0", 
"0", "PG1~1000", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "PG>10000", "0", "0", "PG>10000", "0", "0", "0", 
"PG1001~10000", "0", "0", "PG1~1000", "PG>10000", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "PG1001~10000", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "PG>10000", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "PG>10000")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-340L))
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your question. Could you provid us with a sample of your data so we increase our chance of answering your question correctly?

Comment: I think I added the data to the original post, Is this how I share the sample?

Comment: Yes thank you! However I cannot replicate your example on my machine. When I load your data and run the tbl_summary chunk I get the following error for the `add_p()` function:  `There was an error in 'add_p()/add_difference()' for variable 'PG_Level', p-value omitted:
Error in stats::chisq.test(x = c("PG>10000", "PG>10000", "PG>10000", "PG>10000", : 'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels`.

Comment: ok, sorry, maybe I have typed in the wrong data set, I just updated it in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, the Chi-Square test is a statistical method that can be used to determine if two categorical variables are independent to each other.

So, in your 1st example, you are trying to see if the `Race` is independent to the `PG_Level`.

In your code above, and more precisely in the summary table you show, you only print the rows when `PG_Level` is "PG>10000". However, the "chisq.test" compare the full `Race`column against the full `PG_Level` column.

Let us illustrate this with this example: I took the same code as before while showing all values.

```
DentalHealth %>% select(Race, PG_Level) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = Race, missing = "no") %>%
  add_p(everything() ~ "chisq.test", pvalue_fun = function(x) style_number(x, digits = 3))
```

which gives us:

[image]

As you can see, we have the same p-value here and we print all the values that are fount in the `PG_Level` columns.

And you can optain the same results when you write:

```
chisq.test(x = DentalHealth$Race, y = DentalHealth$PG_Level)
```

> Pearson's Chi-squared test
>
> data:  DentalHealth$Race and DentalHealth$PG_Level X-squared = 10.255,
> df = 6, p-value = 0.1143

I have the impression that what you are trying to do is to see if there are significant differences in the `Race` when `PG_Level` is "PG>10000". That will not be possible with a Chi-squared test.